equivalent of GetKeyDown and GetKey on Unity for UI
    private void AppplyGravity()
     {
        bool falling = velocity.y < 0f || !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space);
        float multiplier = falling ? 2f : 1f;
        velocity.y += gravity * multiplier * Time.deltaTime;
        velocity.y = Mathf.Max(velocity.y, gravity / 2f);
     }

    private void GroundedMovement()
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Max(velocity.y, 0f);
        jumping = velocity.y > 0f;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            velocity.y = jumpForce;
            jumping = true;
        }
        
    }

I'm trying to do this with with button but couldn't figure out how
tried to implement new input system but it's event based and need directly event method but mine is not and need few statement

you can do input.action.ispressed ?

or at least a variant, not in front of unity to check, but there is a input.ispressed option..

I solve my problem with new input system
on Input Actions use the pass through action type and axis control type
add Space key to binding and add on-screen button script to my button and bind with the space key.
    {
    bool isSpaceKeyHeld = playerInput.Movement.Jump.ReadValue<float>() > 0.1f;
    velocity.y = Mathf.Max(velocity.y, 0f);
    jumping = velocity.y > 0f;

    if (isSpaceKeyHeld)
    {
        velocity.y = jumpForce;
        jumping = true;
    }
    
}

and change my code like that and now it's work perfectly fine.

as said you can also do  Jump.WasPressedThisFrame() https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.2/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.html

this one be more helpfull than my solution thanks

well its what i wrote in the comments before hand, i was just on my phone and not going to chase round looking for pages on unity website for you
